# Excel VBA Userform print to dynamic list

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, combobox, userform

I am working on a project where I have a `userform` with multiple `comboboxes`.  The `comboboxes` will output to the cell I specified.  My problem is That I want to have a `button` that ranks the projects based on the `combobox` output. I want the user to be able to change the `combobox` input, click a rank `button` and have the corresponding list change in order.  As you can see below, I used 'Cells(3, 2).Value = C02Combo.Value'. I know this will only output to row 3, but I will need the userform to output to whichever row I selected to open Userform (columns can stay the same). I tried I few things with the "emptyrow" variable in comments below but no luck.  I am a VBA beginner, sorry if the question is not explained properly.

Private Sub enterData_Click()

```
'Dim emptyRow As Long
'Make Sheet1 active
'Model.Activate
'Determine emptyRow
'emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Code to write form data to spreadsheet here
Cells(3, 2).Value = C02Combo.Value
Cells(3, 3).Value = AdminCombo.Value
Cells(3, 4).Value = FacultyCombo.Value
Cells(3, 5).Value = ResearchCombo.Value
Cells(3, 6).Value = EducationCombo.Value
Cells(3, 7).Value = CommunityCombo.Value
Cells(3, 8).Value = InnovationCombo.Value
Cells(3, 9).Value = CostCombo.Value
Cells(3, 10).Value = PaybackCombo.Value
Cells(3, 11).Value = CostPerCutCombo.Value

Unload Me
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You do not say explicitly what is wrong so I have attempted to cover all the bases.

`WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))` counts the number of non-empty cells in the range `A1:An` where `An` is the lowest cell with a value.  If there are any empty cells in this range, you will not get the result you seek.

Excel offers a variety of methods for finding the last row or column; none of which work in every situation.

`Find` is the most generally applicable:

```
  With Sheets("xxxx")
    rowFinal = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    colFinal = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
  End With
```

If the data in worksheet “xxxx” is rectangular, `Cells(rowFinal, colFinal)` will be the bottom, right cell with a value.  If the data is irregular, `Cells(rowFinal, colFinal)` may be empty but there will be no value below it and not value to the right of it.

The most popular method, judging from this site, is:

```
  With Sheets("xxxx")
    rowAFinal = .Cells(Rows.Count, “A”).End(xlUp).Row
  End With
```

This is the VBA equivalent of placing the cursor in the bottom cell of column A and clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>UpArrow</kbd>.  There are complications if there are values at the bottom of column A but normally this will give the last used row in column A.

I am not sure what “I will need the userform to output to whichever row I selected to open Userform” means.  You can identifiy the row containing the cursor with `ActiveCell.Row`.

The above all assume the code in the user form identifies the required row.  If you want the calling module to perform the identification you need something like:

```
  Public emptyRow As Long   ‘ This must be outside all subs and functions

  emptyRow = 27
```

`Dim emptyRow As Long` declares a variable that is private to the module.  The `Public` is required if you want subs in other modules or a user form to have access.

Hope this helps.